# I have already installed NumPy but VSCode doesn't recognize that

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSCnH.png)
Please help!

Although I have already installed numpy library on my computer (even trying more than once), I guess vs code doesn't recognize that installation. I couldn't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: If you don't use a virtual environment, at least make sure to run pip _using_ python (`python -m pip install ...`) so that you know that the _right_ pip is getting used =)

Comment: Just for fun, try `py -3 numpy-basics.py`.

Comment: You have multiple installations of Python

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please get in the habit of showing text, especially code, as text rather than as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

This was usually caused by the incorrect python interpreter.

You could use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter" in VSCode. You could choose the python interpreter which you installed numpy in.

In your case, you have to choose the python311.